# Show an app's live tile in a grid Metro app

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I was wondering if it's possible to show an app's live tile in my own MetroStyle app in Windows 8.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? They already have a Start menu that shows those...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer : no.

Longer answer :  You can't show another app's live tile directly in your app, but you can probably put together something that looks and feels like a live tile.  If the other app is another one of your apps, you can probably send your tile updates to the original app, and also provide the data to the host app (in which you want to show this tile).  It shouldn't be too hard to do, and the Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone has a HubTile control that givers the basis of something similar for that platform.

If the app whose tile you want to access is not something you control, you won't be able to get any of the "live" data due to the heavily sandboxed nature of Metro apps.

Comment: So in general I won't be able to access ANY kind of information on the running apps? Even name of running apps? I was thinking of creating a Full-Screen MetroApp switcher. (Something like StartScreen, but for running apps). Isn't it possible?

Comment: Please take a look at this: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/a9e0ebe7-567a-e011-986b-78e7d1fa76f8 I'm thinking to create a similar app for Windows 8 but just for running apps. Since they're similar, I figured maybe it's possible to do sth like that in Windows 8.